# Is it possible to hide fixed element on scroll when it reaches the footer?

Tags: css

I have an arrow with position fixed to indicate to the users that there are more content below the fold.

[image: Screenshot of a website]

This is the CSS:

```css
.arrow {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 100%;
    transform: translateY(-100%);
    margin: -10px 10px 0 0;
    z-index: 100;
    opacity: 0.4;
}
.arrow svg {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
}
```

I want the arrow to be hidden when it reaches the footer and visible when you scroll up.

Are there any techniques I can use that will be performant? I was trying to use IntersectionObserver, but just found that [it doesn't work with position: fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53403524/387194). I was thinking maybe changing the CSS for it, but I'm not sure how I can have the same effect.

I was trying `position: sticky`. But I'm not sure if you can even use for such a thing.

I was also thinking about use Scroll Drive Animation, but I never used them and don't know if their API allow something like this.

Is there a way to have this behavior with CSS alone, or do I need to use JavaScript and scroll event? I would prefer to use CSS solution or any modern solution that don't involve execution JavaScript on scroll event.

**EDIT** Here is reproduction of the issue.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
.arrow {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 100%;
    transform: translateY(-100%);
    margin: -10px 10px 0 0;
    z-index: 100;
    opacity: 0.4;
}
.arrow svg {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
}
.force-scrollbar {
   height: 1000px;
}
footer {
   background: black;
   height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="force-scrollbar">

</div>

<footer>
<div class="arrow">
<svg width="361.514" height="361.514" viewBox="0 0 95.651 95.651" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g transform="translate(-58.796 -13.995)"><circle style="fill:#e6e6e6;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:none;stroke-width:4.79999;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1" cx="106.621" cy="61.821" r="47.825"></circle><path style="fill:#ff5300;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke-width:3.70417;stroke-linecap:square" d="M94.271 32.634a3.252 3.252 0 0 0-3.26 3.26v31.111h-6.33a2.612 2.01 0 0 0-2.194 3.101l21.58 25.686a2.99 2.3 0 0 0 5.02 0l21.685-25.81a2.507 1.929 0 0 0-2.105-2.977h-6.525V35.894a3.252 3.252 0 0 0-3.26-3.26z"></path></g></svg>
</div>
</footer>
```

Comment: No, you would need JS to track position of scroll in page.

Comment: Does one of these answer your question? [Hide div when user reaches the bottom of page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21379601/how-to-hide-div-when-scroll-reach-at-bottom-through-css) -- [How to hide DIV when scroll reach at Bottom through CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21379601/how-to-hide-div-when-scroll-reach-at-bottom-through-css) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31763329/hide-div-when-user-reaches-the-bottom-of-page?rq=3

Comment: @0stone0 they are old questions where the only option was scroll event. I was asking for something modern without the need to add JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using scroll driven animation you can use the following:

```
footer {
  animation: hide linear;
  animation-timeline: view(block);
  animation-range-start: entry 0%;
  --h: initial;
}

@keyframes hide {
  0.1%,
  100% {
    --h: none;
  }
}
```

When the footer enter the visible part of the scrolling element (we see the footer) you update the variable to `none` and that variable is used to define the display of the footer.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.arrow {
  position: fixed;
  display: var(--h);
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: -10px 10px 0 0;
  z-index: 100;
  opacity: 0.4;
}

.arrow svg {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}

.force-scrollbar {
  height: 1000px;
}

footer {
  background: black;
  height: 200px;
  animation: hide linear;
  animation-timeline: view(block);
  animation-range-start: entry 0%;
  --h: initial;
}

@keyframes hide {
  0.1%,
  100% {
    --h: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="force-scrollbar">

</div>

<footer>
  <div class="arrow">
    <svg width="361.514" height="361.514" viewBox="0 0 95.651 95.651" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g transform="translate(-58.796 -13.995)"><circle style="fill:#e6e6e6;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:none;stroke-width:4.79999;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1" cx="106.621" cy="61.821" r="47.825"></circle><path style="fill:#ff5300;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke-width:3.70417;stroke-linecap:square" d="M94.271 32.634a3.252 3.252 0 0 0-3.26 3.26v31.111h-6.33a2.612 2.01 0 0 0-2.194 3.101l21.58 25.686a2.99 2.3 0 0 0 5.02 0l21.685-25.81a2.507 1.929 0 0 0-2.105-2.977h-6.525V35.894a3.252 3.252 0 0 0-3.26-3.26z"></path></g></svg>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I need to learn more about scroll animations.

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat cheating solution is to rearrange the DOM slightly and bring the footer forward in the third dimension compared to the arrow using `z-index`.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
.arrow {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 100%;
    transform: translateY(-100%);
    margin: -10px 10px 0 0;
    z-index: 100;
    opacity: 0.4;
}
.arrow svg {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
}
.force-scrollbar {
   height: 1000px;
}

footer {
   position: relative; /* here */
   background: black;
   height: 200px;
   z-index: 101; /* here */
}

/* 
You can possibly add a fading layer towards the footer (assuming it's empty space). I created a white shadow effect corresponding to the background. This way it looks like it's "fading out" as you reach the bottom of the page.
*/
footer::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -100px; /* height */
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px; /* height */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="force-scrollbar"></div>

<div class="arrow">
    <svg width="361.514" height="361.514" viewBox="0 0 95.651 95.651" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g transform="translate(-58.796 -13.995)"><circle style="fill:#e6e6e6;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:none;stroke-width:4.79999;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1" cx="106.621" cy="61.821" r="47.825"></circle><path style="fill:#ff5300;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke-width:3.70417;stroke-linecap:square" d="M94.271 32.634a3.252 3.252 0 0 0-3.26 3.26v31.111h-6.33a2.612 2.01 0 0 0-2.194 3.101l21.58 25.686a2.99 2.3 0 0 0 5.02 0l21.685-25.81a2.507 1.929 0 0 0-2.105-2.977h-6.525V35.894a3.252 3.252 0 0 0-3.26-3.26z"></path></g></svg>
</div>

<footer>
  
</footer>
```